# Access multiple WSO2 ESB Management consoles

Tags: soap, registry, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am running on my local Windows machine the WSO2 ESB and WSO2 Governance Reg.
The problem is that I have to alternate their execution, since the management Panel is at the same address: `https://192......:9443/carbon/`
So I can see only one at the time.

What Can I do to access both management panels at different URLS on the same machine?
Or do you think is a bad practise to run both WSO2 platforms on the same machine?

I hope my question is not confusing.
Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run multiple WSO2 Servers (eg. ESB, AS, BPS etc.), by easily switching the ports using the Ports/offset property in the `repository/conf/carbon.xml`. Offset moves all ports by the given value.
By default, the offset property is set to zero. (`https://192......:9443/carbon/`)

To set offset value to 1; (`https://192......:9444/carbon/`) alter following property value in `repository/conf/carbon.xml`

```
<Ports>
<Offset>1</Offset>
----
</Ports>
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Thilini